# mktime & asctime giving random values sometimes correct sometimes year will be 1970

Tags: c++, linux, datetime

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* puts */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, time, localtime, strftime */
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include<unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  char CURRZONE[] = "TZ=Asia/Kolkata";
  char DESTZONE[] = "TZ=UTC";

  time_t stamp;
  struct tm datetime;
  putenv(CURRZONE);
  char buffer[20];
  uint16_t timevec[] = {15,28,12,30,06,2021};
  datetime.tm_year = timevec[5]-1900;
  datetime.tm_mon = timevec[4]-1;
  datetime.tm_mday = timevec[3];
  datetime.tm_hour = timevec[2];
  datetime.tm_min = timevec[1];
  datetime.tm_sec = timevec[0];
  stamp = mktime(&datetime);
  putenv(DESTZONE);
  strftime (buffer,20,"%Y:%m:%d %T",localtime(&stamp));
  std::string str(buffer);
  cout<<str<<"\n";
  return 0;
}
```

it's sometimes giving me the correct output which is 2021:06:30 06:58:15

othertimes it's giving me 1969:12:31 23:59:59

I don't need to compile the program again if I run it again its giving a different value.
This behaviour is in CPP not with C.
Not able to understand the reason behind the same.

Comment: `1969:12:31 23:59:59` corresponds to `(time_t)-1` which is probably an error value.

Comment: Try memsetting `datetime` to zero? Are there not other members in there, which are, perhaps causing `mktime` to set an error value.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Comment: The code does not set `datetime.tm_isdst` which could result in DST being randomly applied or not (although Asia/Kolkata does not use DST).

Comment: `struct tm datetime = {0};` would probably be much safer...

Comment: see [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/995714), [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Answer (score 4):

The error can be reproduced reliably on a system using Glibc's implementation of `mktime` by setting `datetime.tm_isdst` to any positive value. That tells `mktime` that DST is in effect for the supplied time information. That seems to be causing `mktime` to return an error (return value `(time_t)-1` with `errno` set to `EOVERFLOW`), perhaps because DST has not been in effect for `Asia/Kolkata` since October 15, 1945 and `mktime` has no idea what amount of DST correction should be applied. This is probably implementation-dependent<sup>1</sup>.

OP's code leaves `datetime.tm_isdst` uninitialized, so the error occurs randomly (an example of *undefined behavior*). Setting `datetime.tm_isdst` to 0 (meaning DST is not in effect) or a negative value (meaning `mktime` should attempt to determine whether DST is in effect or not) prevents the error occuring.

---

POSIX (but not the C or C++ standards) requires `mktime` to set `errno` to indicate an error. That could be used to determine whether the return value of `(time_t)-1` indicates an error or is an actual time value. By setting `errno = 0;` before the call to `mktime` and checking it afterwards, it can be used to confirm whether the return value of `(time_t)-1` represents a genuinely unsuccessful result or not:

```
    errno = 0;
    stamp = mktime(&datetime);
    if (stamp == (time_t)-1 && errno)
    {
        /* error */
    }
    else
    {
        /* OK */
    }
```

(Note: it is important to use `stamp == (time_t)-1` rather than `stamp == -1` for portability reasons.)

---

<sup>1</sup>  The implementation of `mktime` in the IANA tz distribution code does not return an error under the same conditions and applies a DST offset of 3600 seconds. Perhaps the Glibc implementation could be improved. It looks like the Glibc implementation of `mktime` came from Gnulib, and that if there is a mismatch between the requested `tm_isdst` value and the actual `tm_isdst` value for the specified time, it will search neighboring transitions for a DST offset, but only within a range spanning 536454000 seconds (about 17 years) before and after the specified time. If no `tm_isdst` match is found within that range, it gives up and returns an error with `errno` set to `EOVERFLOW`.

Comment: Thanks for the insights,
what should I do when I have few locations which have DST applicable and need that for accurate conversion and others where DST is not applicable.

Comment: @chetanchadha You can set `tm_isdst` to a negative value if you are not sure if DST is applicable or not, but if the specified time is in a "DST overlap" region (when the clocks go back), the result will be ambiguous.